# Does the javascript formdata keep its insertion order when sending multiple files in one key?

Tags: javascript, multipartform-data

I am trying to send multiple files via FormData object. I have no problem since I know I can append every file to the same key and send it that way. However, I was wondering if the insertion order is preserved and guaranteed. In other words, can I retrieve files on the backend in the same order I have put at frontend? I looked at MDN docs but couldn't find it here.

Comment: I think a better question would be: why would the order matter?

Comment: Well, we need a way to determine which document is DocumentCategoryA, DocumentCategoryB and so on... I suggested sending each file in its own key/value pair but got rejected by the backend guy because the technology they are using wouldn't make it so easy for them. He suggested sending files in one array together with json that would be used for mapping (category -  filename). This is not the ideal solution since uniqueness of the filenames isn't guaranteed.

Comment: as the files have key, there should be ways to access them by key instead of by index

Comment: @MartinTuróci So 3 files in `files[]`, `files[]`, `files[]`, and a `desc` field like `[{"category":"A","filename":"one"},{"category":"B","filename":"two"},{"category":"B","filename":"one"}]`?

Comment: @Bergi I am not sure if I understand. It is more like files[] -> file1.pdf, file2.pdf, file3.pdf and json -> ["CategoryA":"file1.pdf", "CategoryB":"file2.pdf","CategoryC":"file3.pdf"]. It is also important to note that there is 1:1 mapping between category and file.

Comment: @MartinTuróci you can't have an array of files in multipart/formdata, you can only have multiple files with the same field name. It's PHP (and probably some other backends as well) that interpret it like that. What I would suggest to try is using explicit indices `files[0]` file1.pdf, `files[1]` file2.pdf `files[2]` file3.pdf (plus the json), or even using named properties like `files[categoryA]` file1.pdf `files[categoryB]` file2.pdf `files[categoryC]` file3.pdf`. Yes, if the filenames are not guaranteed unique you cannot use them for mapping. Use the indices instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While it's a bit dense, https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/form-control-infrastructure.html#submit-body lists the algorithms that must be followed for the different post methods, so in this case that would be https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/form-control-infrastructure.html#multipart/form-data-encoding-algorithm, which states:

> The order of parts must be the same as the order of fields in entry list. Multiple entries with the same name must be treated as distinct fields.

So the answer seems to be "yes, *if* the user agent correctly implements the serialization of the FormData object".

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the entries of a `FormData` object are kept in an ordered [list](https://xhr.spec.whatwg.org/#concept-formdata-entry-list). When you [`append`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData/append) to that list, the order is kept.

Comment: note that while ordering of the FormData's list is important, the equally important part is that the order is preserved once submission happens (i.e. even if the form list is ordered, the serialization/deserialization algorithms still need to guarantee that ordering is preserved)

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans Yes, (although I had suspected that) thanks for quickly confirming it in your answer :-)

Comment: It's one of those things that makes you go "it... it should be? wait, where the HECK did we document that? O_o" =D